# Setting up a Remote Debugging Environment

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, remote-debugging

I want to develop an application on my machine that is supposed to run on a raspberry pi, which has a thermocouple connected to it. My app shall have (not only in production, but also during development/debugging) access to the thermocouples values.

My planned approach is to deploy the app on the raspberry and connect via intellij's remote debugging configuration to the running app. I want the app to be automatically copied to the raspberry (available in my network) before every run. How can I achieve this? I tried to write an scp script, yet have several problems with windows 10 and certificates.

The app is written in java, I use intellij and windows 10 on my machine. The raspberry is connected via ethernet to my machine and has debian running.

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: You might get a faster answer in raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.